# Suppressing Notifications during Scheduled Maintenance Window in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm working on a complex software system that requires a daily maintenance window from 7AM - 9AM UTC. During this window, I need to suppress notifications from the system to prevent flooding of unneeded alerts. I have come up with the following configuration but I am unable to test it due to restrictions in our environment. I would appreciate if someone could verify its correctness.

Here is the configuration I've proposed:

```
routes:
  - receiver: devs
    mute_time_intervals:
      - xyz_maintenance_hours

time_intervals:
  - name: xyz_maintenance_hours
    time_intervals:
      - times:
          - start_time: "6:50" # UTC
            end_time: "9:10" # UTC
```

A couple of specific questions I have:

1. Have I structured the mute_time_intervals and time_intervals blocks
   correctly?
2. Is the time format "HH:MM" correct for the start_time and end_time
   fields?

Thank you in advance for your guidance!